# Gift link managment

Tags: web-apps, sharing

I buy many games in bundles.  Sometimes this leaves me with an extra copy because I've already bought the game before, and sometimes the bundle explicitly includes multiple copies of a game.

In turn, rather than being Steam-giftable links, the bundle sites usually have their own format for gifting these extra keys to other people.  Humble Bundle offers links to `www.humblebundle.com/gift?key=...`, for instance.  Over time, I've accumulated a lot of these links.  Now I want to do something with them.

Is there a website, application, or service I can use to keep track of unclaimed keys and links, preferably with a way I can offer them to my friends?  Being able to trade them more generally would be even more useful, but I'll settle for a single manager that my friends can periodically check to see if there's anything they want.

---

Specifically, what I'm looking for would have:

- Support for putting both Steam keys and arbitrary redemption URLs in.
- A way to share my library, or *at least* the list of games in it to other people.

  - The ability for people to automatically claim something is desired, but not critical.
  - The ability to trade with other users of the site would also be a nice to have.

It does *not* have to be a website - a local application which can generate a report would work.  It just makes more sense to me as a webapp.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.steamgifts.com/ this is the type of site that you're looking for.

Using this, you can enter for game giveaways and giveaway your own games.

It also tallys the amount that you've given away (money-wise) so that you can enter giveaways with a minimum amount given away (e.g a giveaway with a minimum of £5/$5 worth of games given away).

Comment: Interesting.  That definitely seems to meet my first requirement, and the overall goal, but it doesn't seem to have any way to input the list of links/keys and use it as a library.  I'd either have to create all the giveaways/trades at once, or still have to keep track of each bundle's links separately.

Comment: @Bobson it rolls the giveaways for you and just gives you a link/email to send the links to. Every site I know of does it this way, sorry